# Why does 'bpy.ops.nla.fmodifier_add' fail due to 'context is incorrect' error?

Tags: python, nla-editor

My nla strip confirmed that the active attribute is True, but `bpy.ops.nla.fmodifier_add` failed due to the `context is correct` error. What's the reason? For you, I attach my blender work screen and api capture image.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You apparently have to override the context to make Blender believe you are inside the NLA editor.

```
import bpy

win    = bpy.context.window
scr    = win.screen
area   = [area for area in scr.areas if area.type == 'NLA_EDITOR'][0]
region = area.regions[0]

override = {
    'window': win,
    'screen': scr,
    'area'  : area,
    'region': region,
    'scene' : bpy.context.scene,
}

bpy.ops.nla.fmodifier_add(override, type="STEPPED", only_active=True)
```

Of course this only works if there *is* an NLA editor area open. Otherwise you'll have to create one first.

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly for me. I never knew there was a third hidden parameter. To infer that, I probably need a deeper understanding of Python's inheritance.

Comment: If you are interested, please take a look at [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/228577/how-to-add-modifier-to-an-nla-strip-using-python). It's a question about how to add an NLA strip modifier without using ops.

Comment: Having to pretend to be in a particular area is certainly one of the stupider bits of Blender operators. Unfortunately I don't think there's a way to do it without an op here.